# Getting hirefire to work with Rails 3.1.3, DJ 3.0.0, Heroku Cedar Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, hirefire

I'm trying to get [hirefire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) to work with Heroku Cedar Stack. I tried using [this](https://gist.github.com/1082673) patch, but that doesn't seem to help either. Workers are not getting spun up at all. Anybody here has a solution that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this after I looked at hirefire source. The issue in my case was that there was a locked job in the job queue. Because of this, delayed_job.working turned out to be 1 and not 0. Also, because of the locked job, delayed_job.jobs was also 1. And hence no worker was hired. I cleared all the jobs from the queue and then hirefire worked like a charm.

```
    def hirefire_hire
      delayed_job = ::Delayed::Job.new
      if delayed_job.working == 0 \
      or delayed_job.jobs    == 1
        environment.hire
      end
    end
```

I think this check should be modified to check for number of jobs that are not locked or something of a similar nature.